# How to count the suffixes in words contained in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have previously found a way to count the prefixes, as shown below, so is there a way similar to this which is so obvious I'm missing it completely?

```
for i in range (0, len(hardprefix)):
    if len(word) > len(hardprefix[i]):
            if word.startswith(hardprefix[i]):
                hardprefixcount += 1
                break
```

I need this code to use the first column of the file and count the number of a set array of suffixes found within these words

This is what i have so far

```
for i in range (0, len(easysuffix)):
    if len (word) > len(easysuffix[i]):
            if word.endswith(easysuffix[i]):
                easysuffixcount += 1
                break
```

below is a sample of my data from the csv file, with the arrays using the suffixes below that

```
on  1
only    4
our 1
own 1
part    7
piece   4
pieces  4
place   1
pressed 1
riot    1
september   1
shape   3

hardsuffix = ['ism']
easysuffix = ['ity', 'esome', 'ece']
```

Comment: add a small sample input and you expected output

Comment: Although it could be improved, your code looks like it should work. What is the actual problem? Reading from a CSV file or something else?

Comment: the problem is it keeps producing a result of 0

Comment: The sample of data doesn't look like it's from a csv - there aren't any commas! If this is correct, then do the values of `word` include the numbers as part of them? If so, then this could be why you're not picking up the suffixes.

Comment: `easysuffixcount` is being initialized outside of the outermost for loop, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input file is tab delimited CSV so you can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to process it.

```
import csv

suffixes = ['ity', 'esome', 'ece']

with open('input.csv') as words:
    suffix_count = 0
    reader = csv.reader(words, delimiter='\t')
    for word, _ in reader:
        if any(word.endswith(suffix) for suffix in suffixes):
            suffix_count += 1

print "Found {} suffix(es)".format(suffix_count)
```